# Email ID Validation in C++ in Blackberry 10

Tags: regex, blackberry-10, email-validation

I want to validate an email id entered by the use inside a textfield from C++ in Blackberry 10 App.

Can anyone suggest how it can be done ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what does an email id look like?  Is this an email address or a blackberry user format?  If the latter what does that look like?

Comment: it a normal looking email address

Comment: Do you just want to check the input format, or do you ask for a validation, if the mail address is valid AND an active mail address the user has access to?

Comment: just check the input format

Answer (score 1):

Use the Validator API added in 10.1: cascades_validator.html">https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*cascades*_validator.html

You would need to supply your own regex to match an email though. There are lots of examples that do that on the Internet. You can start with (and maybe just end with) the information on http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html